# Trigger.IO Facebook Authorize Not Opening Login Page

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, facebook, trigger.io

### tl;dr;

**Issue 1**: iOS simulator would hang when trying to facebook.authorize.  Safari would open with the facebook mobile URL, but the page would not render.

**Solution 1**: Mis-spelled the permission (publish_actions).  Make sure the permissions and audience are spelled properly.

**Issue 2**: iOS simulator (7.0.3) would complete the facebook.authorize process, but the same code on my iPhone 5 (7.0.4) would always return 'Login failed'.  Here's a screencast of the issue: http://youtu.be/yQiYMFH5y3U

**Solution 2**: In Settings > Facebook, there is a list of apps that have (or don't have) permission to access Facebook natively via the SDK.  My app was marked as disabled in the list.  Make sure the application is enabled in the list.

---

When using the Facebook Module on Trigger.IO for authorization on an iPhone, the **forge.facebook.authorize** API call is not opening the Facebook authorization window as expected.

From the [Trigger.IO Facebook Module docs](https://trigger.io/modules/facebook/current/docs/index.html) for **forge.facebook.authorize**:

> Authorize the current user with Facebook. May show a login UI if new permissions are required, or a valid login token is not available (i.e. on first login).

Instead, the **error** callback is being called with this message:

> {"message":"Login failed","type":"EXPECTED_FAILURE","subtype":null}

Running the same code in the iOS simulator (v7.0.3) opens the Facebook web login prompt as expected.

Calling **forge.facebook.hasAuthorized** returns this error, as expected:

> {"message":"User not logged in or insufficient read permissions","type":"EXPECTED_FAILURE","subtype":null}

The call for **forge.facebook.authorize** is without any permissions or audience parameters; just the success and error callbacks.

Testing Configuration:

- Trigger.IO v2.1.4
- Facebook Module v2.3
- iPhone 5 (iOS 7.0.4)
- Facebook iOS App v8.0

Any ideas on how to get the **forge.facebook.authorize** function to open the Facebook login prompt?

**Update #1:**

I managed to get the error to reproduce on the iOS Simulator. I tried adding the **permissions** and **audience** parameters and I think the issue is the **audience** parameter is not being parsed as a string when being sent to Facebook, which is causing the request to error out.

Here's the log output:

    `[   INFO] 2014-03-24 17:39:39.750 Forge[9247:a0b] [DEBUG] Native call: {
    [   INFO]     callid = "31F68389-DE82-4F71-A689-213E008A28E6";
    [   INFO]     method = "facebook.authorize";
    [   INFO]     params =     {
    [   INFO]         audience = friends;
    [   INFO]         dialog = 1;
    [   INFO]         permissions =         (
    [   INFO]             "read_stream",
    [   INFO]             "public_actions"
    [   INFO]         );
    [   INFO]     };
    [   INFO]     start = "1395697179.74";
    [   INFO] }
    [   INFO] 2014-03-24 17:39:39.937 Forge[9247:1503] [WARNING] Error reporting partner data to Facebook`

**Update #2:**

Removing the **permissions** and **audience** parameters works on the iOS Simulator:

    `[   INFO] 2014-03-24 18:28:22.652 Forge[10387:a0b] [DEBUG] Native call: {
    [   INFO]     callid = "22233011-4A9F-41E0-841E-4616E9E944D9";
    [   INFO]     method = "facebook.authorize";
    [   INFO]     params =     {
    [   INFO]         dialog = 0;
    [   INFO]         permissions =         (
    [   INFO]         );
    [   INFO]     };
    [   INFO]     start = "1395700102.606";
    [   INFO] }`

Comment: It all seems to work for me on Trigger.io API v2.1.3, Facebook module v2.3, iPhone 5s (iOS 7.1) and same Facebook app version as you. I'm calling `forge.facebook.authorize(['email'], 'none', callback);`. Hope this helps debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"public_actions" is not a valid permission string.

Did you perhaps mean "publish_actions" ?

The full list of permissions is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

Comment: This was the first issue I ran into.  Thanks for pointing that out!